# AutoLayout constrain for a view to be right above the keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Would someone be so kind telling me how would you set a constrain (using size classes) for a view to be right above the keyboard (without the predictive part) on iP6 and iP6+ like on the photo below?

May I have a sample project?

Thank you

[image: ios]

[image: layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add the constraints in programmatically based on the keyboard size, or make separate interface files for every screen size with a fixed constraint based on a known size for the keyboard for that screen.

Comment: OK, I created a separate storyboard for iP6+, loaded it in the AppDelegate. It's not perfect but at least it works. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link to a chat application that works from the same premise. When the keyboard is active elements are pushed up so they aren't hidden by it.

https://github.com/oseparovic/MessageComposerView

The application is in Objective C and pretty easy to transfer that section of the app, I've used this myself.

Comment: That's not what I want. I'd like a fixed UI. Let me show you: [IMAGE](http://i.imgur.com/absQs8m.jpg) What I'm really asking  is what kind of constrains do I have to set to achieve this layout on both iP6 and 6+. The real question is the 6+ because 6 is the same as 4 and 5.